# For apphp framework i need to preform ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller, frameworks

APPHP framework , i have datatable when i click on action button "edit", I need to populate modal form whit data from db.

Jquery is not option because fw blocked ajax request.

If on click call windows.location="controller/action", this action reload page and close my modal. I need to call controller from view on button click, without reloading page.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare data for each Edit link while loading page, please it in Javascript array and use it when you call popup by clicking on [Edit] link